# How to create an instance of a class based on another instance?

Tags: python, oop

For the class I'm writing I want to implement methods to dump the data to a shelve file and also a classmethod that would create a new instance based on the values of the instance loaded from file. So for example if I have a class like that:

```
import shelve

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    def save(self, fname):
        with shelve.open(fname, flag='c') as shlv:
            shlv['data'] = self
```

At the moment I'm using an external function to load the shelve file and return a saved instance:

```
def load_data(filename) -> Foo:
    with shelve.open(filename) as shlv:
        return shlv['data']
```

And this works fine.

I was just trying to think of how I can implement a class method that would load the data and create a new instance.

I'm pretty sure that what I'm thinking is an ugly solution but I'm still interested out of pure curiosity.

My original idea was to do something like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    def save(self, fname):
        with shelve.open(fname, flag='c') as shlv:
            shlv['data'] = self
    
    @classmethod
    def from_saved_data(cls, data):
        cls.__dict__ = data.__dict__
        return cls
```

This doesn't work because I was trying to do dumb things to the metaclass and got this error:

```
AttributeError: attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

What are the other ways I can do this?

Comment: `cls` is the actual class, not an instance. Is `instance = cls(); instance.__dict__ = data.__dict__; return instance` what you want?

Comment: @alkasm, yes, I can create an instance in the way you suggested but since `Foo` requires parameter `a` for initialisation, I need to do something like `instance = cls(data.a)` and then everything is the same.

Comment: If you call `cls.__new__` yourself, it won't automatically call `__init__()` on the instance.